# Not doing anything in function to close the panel

Tags: ractivejs

```
<div class="close" on-click='close'></div>


Ractive.components['block:close'] = Ractive.extend({
  isolated: true,
  onrender: function() {

    this.on({
      close : function(event) {
        console.log('close');
      }
    })
  }
  });
```

When trying to click on the 'x' button, it doesn't show "close" in console.log. 
Not sure why it is not doing anything.

Also looked up ractivejs on google for the animation (fade out) when click close. Couldn't find a way without using JQuery

Comment: Please, provide a little bit more context so we can define what is the problem is. Regarding the animations checkout http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive-transitions-instance

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what's going on in your example - this works fine!

```js
Ractive.components['block:close'] = Ractive.extend({
  isolated: true,
  template: '<div class="close" on-click="close">click me</div>',
  onrender: function() {
    this.on({
      close: function(event) {
        alert('it works');
      }
    });
  }
});

var ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '<block:close/>'
});
```

```html
<script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js'></script>

<main></main>
```

To add fades and other transitions, you need to use [transition plugins](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/transitions). For example:

```js
new Ractive({
  el: 'main',
  template: '#template'
});
```

```html
<script src='http://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js'></script>
<script src='https://rawgit.com/ractivejs/ractive-transitions-fade/master/dist/ractive-transitions-fade.js'></script>

<main></main>

<script id='template' type='text/html'>
  <label>
    <input type='checkbox' checked='{{visible}}'>
    visible (click me)
  </label>
  
  {{#if visible}}
    <div intro='fade'>this will fade in</div>
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

See [the ractive-transitions-fade GitHub repo](https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive-transitions-fade) for more info.

Comment: alot thanks but I couldn't use transitions plugin in the project :( is it possible to use CSS for fade out? I think it should be.

Comment: Why couldn't you use the transitions plugin, is there a bug somewhere? The plugin uses CSS (where possible, falling back to JS timer if nec) - though you could certainly use manually defined CSS animations/transitions